# Debugging prettified Js in Firefox - Quantum

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox pretty print js, whenever a breakpoint is added, the breakpoint is added in original file, making the developer to go through the multiple unwanted lines of code to debug. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently (as of Firefox 63) a lot of bugs around pretty-printing and setting breakpoints in the Firefox DevTools. Regarding your problem, I'd say that's covered in [issue 6947](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/6947). You may also want to see the [list of bugs around pretty-printing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=pretty%20printed&list_id=14425316).

As far as I know, Mozilla is actively working on fixing them, but one workaround might be to use [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map), which allow you to work with the original sources instead of the minified files when debugging. It's hard to debug minified code, anyway.